# commons-logging config: use SimpleLog & set debug level

Tags: java, configuration, logging

I have a commons-logging configuration question.

I want it to use SimpleLog (instead of java.util.logging) and log all messages with level >= debug (instead of info).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [commons-logging docs](http://commons.apache.org/logging/guide.html#Creating%20a%20Log%20Implementation), you should be able to explicitly configure it to use `SimpleLog` by placing a `commons-logging.properties` file in the root of your classpath with the following entry:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog
```

You can then [configure SimpleLog itself](http://commons.apache.org/logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog.html) by placing a `simplelog.properties` file in your classpath root containing this:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog=debug
```

However, I'd recommend against doing any of this. `java.util.logging` is nasty, but it's better than `SimpleLog`, and log4j is better than all of them.

Comment: and logback is better then all of them ;). If came to this question via the context of cayenne, trying to stop it from outputing these annoying info messages to stderr (which seems to be the default to j.u.l). Anyways, thanks for the quick and to the point answer.